# Discrete mathematics for someone from a non-mathematical background

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, recreational-mathematics

I have been a software programmer for over six years and I'm from a non-mathematical background. Though I had some limited exposure to discrete mathematics in my college years it didn't leave any significant impact on me; but now I have been finding many topics on discrete mathematics to be very interesting, especially combinatorics and I'm interested in learning more of it.

However few people I had approached told me that I need to first master calculus in order to take on discrete math, as they say that's how it is taught in universities, is this true? do I need know calculus to appreciate discrete math?
(Also, can anyone point me to any books on combinatorics for beginners)

Comment: In short, no. You do not need calculus to approach discrete math.

Comment: Any book entitled "mathematics for computer science" is good.

Comment: Agree with @mixedmath. I'm originally a compsci, but more recently I've learnt maths / calculus. I loved discrete mathematics when I did my compsci degree, and I can safely say that having done calculus now at degree level, it's not relevant to discrete mathematics.

Comment: If you can read German, I can recommend "Diskrete Mathematik für Einsteiger" from Beutelspacher (ISBN 978-3-8348-1248-3). No university-level math is required to understand this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is termed discrete mathematics is largely independent of calculus. In fact, to appreciate calculus properly, one might need some logic and set theory which is often part of a course in discrete mathematics together with other topics like combinatorics, graph theory and elementary number theory. For a good elementary text in combinatorics, I recommend *Principles and Techniques of Combinatorics* by Chen Chuan Chong and Koh Khee Meng.